# Copying template code into a page

Tags: jquery

I'd like to have some html DIVs tucked away at the bottom of my page with display:none.  Periodically I want to copy one of these DIVs, make some custom changes (display:block, for one) , and insert it somewhere in the DOM.  At the end of the operation the template DIV should still be at the bottom of the page unchanged.

I'm wondering if someone could suggest the best jQuery to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: did you try something? jQuery .css(); clone(). append(). insertAfter()

Comment: How about googling "jquery copy div"?

Comment: Why do the DIVs need to exist and be hidden? Can you create them on the fly? Then you'd not be "making custom changes", you'd just be setting params and properties.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I want the DIVs to pre-exist because some of them may be quite large.  So after I have the HTML for it worked out, I don't want to fool with recreating it from scratch every time, with code that could be difficult to follow and error prone. Some of these DIVs may also get inserted more than once.  So it seemed easier to create a working version of the DIV once and then slap it where I want, adding only code to make small changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with couzzi above, these should be dynamically created. Howver, this is how I interpreted your question (simple concept): http://jsfiddle.net/5xJBN/

```
<div>You can see me!</div>

<div id="append"></div>

<input type="button" value="click me" id="btn"/>

<div id="hidden1" style="display: none;">You cant see this!</div>
```

You can see above the div at the bottom is hidden. I'm going to select it, take the content out, append it to the div with ID: append, and change the color to red (on a button click).

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
var hiddenDiv = $("#hidden1").html();
$("#append").html(hiddenDiv).css("color", "red");
});
```

The hidden div remains unchanged, and unseen.

Comment: Thanks for putting the jsFiddle together.  The only problem with it is that the #append div won't be there yet so I'll have to create it with something like $('<div></div').html . . .